# Xcode UItextField Transparency

Tags: storyboard, uitextfield, xcode9

I figured out how to make the UITextField transparent, but I now need to make the placeholder text white. Is this possible? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
textField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:placeholderText attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color}];
```